# selection files and folders in nautilus

Tags: nautilus

Wondered then a question. When selecting a few folders in nautilus which, in turn, have the files and other directories, which, in turn, is also the files, in nautilus by selecting "properties" from the context menu [shows only the number of all objects inside](http://itmages.ru/image/view/382987/492bb473), ie . considers the number of files together, and the number of subdirectories. How to make shown separately the number of files and number of directories, ie, how many of those and those?

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** This doesn't answer the question, see comments.

I suppose you are searching for the information in the status area of nautilus. This is a screenshot from Ubuntu 10.10:

[image]

Comment: No, you don't understand. I need an information about an amount files and directories separately(not just the amont of all items), like f.e. in dolphin http://itmages.ru/image/view/383164/bc4c2afc, to see an information how many files and how many subdirectories in direcory.

Comment: Oh sorry. I don't think this is possible with Nautilus. I could provide a solution with command line, but I don't think this is what you are searching for.

Comment: Ok, give a command line solution. ...But, still, its very strange that nautilus cannot do this, maybe it can do this with some extension?

Comment: It seems to me to be a very uncommon problem, so I would expect to find any extensions or ready solutions. But I don't know, just guessing.

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly what you asked for, but you can use the command line in order to count folders and files seperately:

This will find the number of folders including the one given by `<path to dir>`:

```
find <path to dir> -type d|wc -l
```

This counts the number of *regular* files, symlinks etc. are not counted here:

```
find <path to dir> -type f|wc -l
```

Comment: If you find the answer useful, you can upvote it or accept it or both... ;)